# Sylow $2$-subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G:={\rm SL}(2,5)$. I want to prove that if $P \in {\rm Syl}_2(G)$, then $P \cong Q_8$. Also i want to know $n_2(G)=5$.

MY TRY: I know $|G|=120=2^3 \times 3 \times 5$. Thus $|P|=8$. If $P$ is cyclic, then $G$ is solvable, a contradiction. So $P$ is non-cyclic. I need to show $P$ is non-abelian and all maximal subgroups of $P$ are cyclic. 
I know $Z(G) \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$ is only non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/Z(G) \cong A_5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a $2$-Sylow group in $G=SL(2,\Bbb F_5)$. The general linear group over this field has $(5^2-1)(5^2-5)=480$ elements. The determinant $\det :GL(2,\Bbb F_5)\to \Bbb F_5^\times$ is surjective, so the kernel has $480/4=120=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5$ elements. The group $P$ has thus $8$ elements. To see which can be the its structure, let us first find all $g\in G$ which have order among $1,2,4,8$. There is only one element in $G$ of order $1$, the unit (matrix) $1\in G$,
$$1=\begin{bmatrix}1&\\&1\end{bmatrix}\ .$$
Let $$g=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$ be an element of order $2$. Then its minimal polynomial divides $X^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)$. It cannot be $X^2-1$, since the determinant is $1$. So it is $X\pm 1$. So there exists exactly one element of order two in $G$, this is $-1$,
$$-1=\begin{bmatrix}-1&\\&-1\end{bmatrix}\ .$$
Now let us find all matrices $g\in G$ with order $4$ or $8$. The minimal polynomial of $g$ divides $X^4-1$, respectively $X^8-1$. We have the decompositions in $R=\Bbb F_5[X]$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X^4-1 &= (X-1)(X-2)(X-3)(X-4)\ ,\\
X^8-1 &= (X^4-1)(X^4+1)\\
&=(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)(X-4)\cdot (X^2-2)(X^2-3)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The only chance to use two eigenvalues in the list of the roots of the above polynomials, so that their product is (the determinant) $1$, is to use $2,3$. (Or double eigenvalues, $+1$, or $-1$, already considered.)

This implies that we have no element $g\in G$ of order $8$.

An element in $G$ has order $4$, iff its characteristic polynomial is $(X-2)(X-3)=X^2+1$, so iff it has trace zero, i.e.
$$g=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{bmatrix}
\ ,\qquad
-a^2-bc=1\ .$$

- We may choose $a\in 2,3$, then $bc=0$, and we have $5+5-1$ possibilities for the pair $(b,c)$. This counting gives us $18$ elements of order $4$.
- We may choose $a\in 1,4$, then $bc=3$, and there are $4$ possibilities for $b\ne 0$, which determine $c$. We obtain $8$ more elements of order $4$.
- The final choice is $a=0$, getting $4$ more elements of order $4$.

So there are totally
$$ 18+ 8 +4 = 30$$
elements of order $4$ in $G$. (And no elements of order $8$, so $P$ is not cyclic, $P\not\cong \Bbb Z/8$.)

From here, $P$ cannot be abelian. Since else it would have the structure $\Bbb Z/4\times \Bbb Z/2$, (or $\Bbb Z/2\times \Bbb Z/2\times \Bbb Z/2$...) contradiction with the existence of exactly one element of order two in $G$.

So $P$ is a dihedral group of order $8$.

Now we need further information to get $n_2(G)$. So let us list all matrices of order four:

```
[0 1]  [0 2]  [0 3]  [0 4]  [1 1]  [1 2]  [1 3]  [1 4]  [2 0]  [2 0]
[4 0], [2 0], [3 0], [1 0], [3 4], [4 4], [1 4], [2 4], [0 3], [1 3],

[2 0]  [2 0]  [2 0]  [2 1]  [2 2]  [2 3]  [2 4]  [3 0]  [3 0]  [3 0]
[2 3], [3 3], [4 3], [0 3], [0 3], [0 3], [0 3], [0 2], [1 2], [2 2],

[3 0]  [3 0]  [3 1]  [3 2]  [3 3]  [3 4]  [4 1]  [4 2]  [4 3]  [4 4]
[3 2], [4 2], [0 2], [0 2], [0 2], [0 2], [3 1], [4 1], [1 1], [2 1]
```

We can explicitly construct now a group of order $8$ by suitably choosing two different elements $s,t$ in the above list. The group $P(s,t)=\langle s, t\rangle$, if it is a group, has then the elements 
$$1,t,-1=t^2=s^2,-t=t^3;\ s,-s;\ st, ts\ .$$
So $sts$ is an other element, it must be in the list. The only chance is 
$$sts=t\ .$$
So each $P$ is of the form:
$$
P(s,t)=\langle s, t\rangle
=\{\ 1,-1,\ t,-t,\ s,-s,\  st, -st=ts\ \}\ ,\qquad sts=t\ ,\ tst=s\ .
$$

One possible realization is with:
$$
P_0= \left\langle
\ 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2\\ 2& 0\end{bmatrix}
\ ,\ 
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0& 3\end{bmatrix}
\ \right\rangle
$$
We can draw a graph by joining two elements $(s,t)$ among the $30$ iff they satisfy $sts=t$. (Then $tst=t$.) Even better, use in the graph only one vertex for a pair $\{s,-s\}$ generating the same group with four elements.

Here is the restricted list of $15$ representatives $\hat s$ for the pair $\{s,s^{-1}\}$:

```
[0 1]  [0 2]  [1 1]  [1 2]  [1 3]  [1 4]  [2 0]  [2 0]  [2 0]  [2 0]
[4 0], [2 0], [3 4], [4 4], [1 4], [2 4], [0 3], [1 3], [2 3], [3 3],

[2 0]  [2 1]  [2 2]  [2 3]  [2 4]
[4 3], [0 3], [0 3], [0 3], [0 3]
```

The corresponding graph is
[image]

it splits in five triangle connected components, coresponding to edges of the shape $s\to t\to \pm st\to s$ for suitable element.
With this analysis, we see there are exactly 
$$n_2(G)=5$$
$2$-Sylow subgroups, explicitly realized.

An other way to get this number is as follows.
The element 
$$u=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1\\2&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has order $3$ and normalizes $P_0$, since
$$
u
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &\\&3
\end{bmatrix}
u^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 &2\\2&
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
So $u$ is an element in the normalizer $N$ of $P_0$. A Sylow theorem
tells us that $n_2(G)=|G:N|$. How many element can have $N$? It contains the group $P$ and an element of order $3$, so $|N|$ is a multiple of $24$. Only $24$ and $120$ can be possible. In the first case there are $120:24=5$ Sylow groups, which is the case. Since the second case with exactly $120:120=1$ Sylow group can be excluded, one can construct two.

Comment: You write $P$ is a dihedral group of order $8$, but we want to show that $P$ is the quaternion group.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P$ has exactly one subgroup of order $2$, by a Theorem. $P$ is cyclic or generalized quaternion group. Clearly, $P$ is non-cyclic and since $|P| =8$, $P \cong Q_8$.

Comment: What theorem are you quoting?